# Why is this Task not Finishing before my code passes the Wait Command

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

I have a task which runs a loop and delays for an interval each iteration.  Once the `CancellationTokenSource` calls `Cancel()` I want my main code to `Wait()` for the `Task.Delay(interval)` to finish and the task to exit the loop before my code continues.  I thought this code would work but it doesn't.

Instead my main code passes the `t.Wait()` before the Loop exits. Why?

**Main Method Code:**

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;

var t = Task.Run(() => { MyLoopTask(200, ct); });

// Prepare information

cts.Cancel();
t.Wait();    

// Send Information
```

**Task Code**

```
private async Task MyLoopTask(int interval, CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Debug.Print("   Still In Loop     ");
        // Do something
        await Task.Delay(interval);
    }

    Debug.Print("   cancelled     ");
    //Clean up
}
```

Comment: Post code for `cts` and `ct`

Comment: I would like to see more of the Main Method code in order to figure out what's going on.

Comment: it is pretty big, i'll try and parse it down to meaningful chunk.

Comment: `t` executes `MyLoopTask`, which, itself, returns a *new* `Task`. Which all of your code ignores. `t` completed almost immediately, because *that* `Task` had very little work to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You create a task with `Task.Run` that fires and forgets the actual task you get back from `MyLoopTask`.

`Task.Run` is redundant here. You can just call `MyLoopTask` and use the task it returns.

```
var t = MyLoopTask(200, ct);
// ...
t.Wait();
```

If you still have some reason to use `Task.Run` you can do so by making sure the delegate waits for the actual task by awaiting it:

```
var t = Task.Run(async () => await MyLoopTask(200, ct));
// ...
t.Wait();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I see what you are saying - the Task.Run created a Task object that set off my method and since that method was also asynchronous the Task.Run task object immediately finished.  It makes sense.

Comment: @AdamHeeg Yes. Technically the outer `Task` completes in the first asynchronous point in your method which is the first time `Task.Delay` is awaited.

Comment: `var t = Task.Run(() => MyLoopTask(200, ct));` would work too.